# Why I am not able to re-mount my encrypted hdd after unmounting it?

Tags: encryption, partitioning

I encrypted the hdd and mounted it; I did not add any data to it. When I unmount it and then remount it, the partition no longer shows in lsblk. Originally, it would show the name I gave the hdd, for example, "/dev/mapper/exthdd". But when I remount it, lsblk just shows "/dev/sdx". If I try to mount it with the original partition name, not surprisingly, it does not work. If I try to re-encrypt the whole disk from scratch, and use the same name "/dev/mapper/exthdd, it tells me that it already exists, even though the 1st step or two in re-encrypting were supposed to delete everything.

I don't know why remounting it causes the partition and encryption to disappear.

Comment: Did you `cryptsetup close` and `cryptsetup open`?

Comment: @user yes, i did. I noticed that when the 'superblocks' were being created, that instead of running through all 15,000 'units', it started and 2 seconds later it said it was completed. The first time that i encrypted it took 15 minutes to run through all of them. This fast 'creating superblock' thing has happened the last few times I have encrypted it.

Comment: I don't think the superblock 'thing' was the problem as I noticed the same thing happen on a different computer with a different set of commands.

Comment: I redid the closing and this time it worked. Thanks.